# Ether.li: Recovery

Tags: private-key, backup, ether.li

someone has a problem with ether.li. After it did not sign transactions, he accidently deleted his accounts. But all data is still here:

- Address
- Backup private Key
- Encrypted private key
- User Key Adress
- Backup Key Adress
- Co-signer Adress

My plan is to extract the private keys and use parity to import them. Is the data here enough? Do I need to extract priv keys from the browser or something like this?

I'm a bit confused. How is the private key encrypted? (some way to decrypt it without ether.li)? What's the difference between encrypted private key and backup address?

Comment: I need the same information. Ether.li has problens and I need to import in other way like parity. But I cant figure out!